# How to create matrix of nearest neighbours from dataset using matrix of indices - matlab

Tags: matlab

I have an `Nx2` matrix of data points where each row is a data point. I also have an `NxK` matrix of indices of the `K` nearest neighbours from the `knnsearch` function. I am trying to create a matrix that contains in each row the data point followed by the K neighbouring data points, i.e. for `K = 2` we would have something like `[data1, neighbour1, neighbour2]` for each row.

I have been messing round with loops and attempting to index with matrices but to no avail, the fact that each datapoint is `1x2` is confusing me.
My ultimate aim is to calculate gradients to train an RBF network in a similar manner to:

```
D = (x_dist - y_dist)./(y_dist+(y_dist==0));
temp = y';
neg_gradient = -2.*sum(kron(D, ones(1,2)) .* ...
    (repmat(y, 1, ndata) - repmat((temp(:))', ndata, 1)), 1);
neg_gradient = (reshape(neg_gradient, net.nout, ndata))';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something along those lines:

```
K = 2;
nearest = knnsearch(data, data, 'K', K+1);%// Gets point itself and K nearest ones
mat = reshape(data(nearest.',:).',[],N).'; %// Extracts the coordinates
```

We generate `data(nearest.',:)` to get a `3*N-by-2` matrix, where every 3 consecutive rows are the points that correspond to each other. We transpose this to get the xy-coordinates into the same column. (MATLAB is column major, i.e. values in a column are stored consecutively). Then we reshape the data, so every column contains the xy-coordinates of the rows of `nearest`. So we only need to transpose once more in the end.